# Convert a 2d array of NSIntegers to a color-coded grid representation of the array

Tags: ios, objective-c, multidimensional-array

What I am trying to simulate here is random map generation. The random generation and computing is already done and stored in a 2D array of NSIntegers (about 400x400) where the value of each element represents the color of the tile on the map (ex: 1 = green, 2 = blue). What I want to do is display the 2D array as a colored grid on the user's screen.

I am having trouble figuring out the right way to do this. Options I have considered are drawing points with UIImage and drawing 1pt rectangles with CGRect.

What is the best way to do this? Code samples would be very helpful here.

Comment: Down voting without a comment is not very useful.

Comment: I would say you have to write a custom UIView subclass that can draw the array, via `drawrect:`, etc.  And upvoting to counter downvote as this is a well asked question.  Finally if you are using an index-based colour system then you probably want an array of `uint8_t` to save lots of wasted bits.

Comment: What is the best way to pass the 2D array to the UIView subclass? I'm still relatively new to Objective-C